# Splitting remote EJB functionality between different remote objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, remoting

I am working on a legacy system, where there is a remote bean that has become too big and monolithic, and I would like to keep separate the new functionality I that need to add.

My initial idea was, instead of adding my new methods to the existing interface, create a new interface with all my stuff and add a single method that returns a remote object implementing my interface.

The problem I am facing now is that when I'm invoking the method that returns my object, the runtime tries to serialize it instead of sending the stub.

The code layout is more or less like this:

```
@Stateless
public class OldBean implements OldRemoteInterface {
   //lots of the old unrelated methods here

   public MyNewStuff getMyNewStuff() {
      return new MyNewStuff();
   }
}

@Remote
public interface OldRemoteInterface {
   //lots of the old unrelated methods declared here

   MyNewStuff getMyNewStuff();
}

public class MyNewStuff implements NewRemoteInterface {
   //methods implemented here
}

@Remote
public interface NewRemoteInterface {
   //new methods declared here
}
```

And the exception I am getting is:

```
"IOP00810267: (MARSHAL) An instance of class MyNewStuff could not be marshalled:
the class is not an instance of java.io.Serializable"
```

I have tried to do it "the old way", extending the `java.rmi.Remote` interface instead of using the ejb `@Remote` annotation, and the exception I get is:

```
"IOP00511403: (INV_OBJREF) Class MyNewStuff not exported, or else is actually 
a JRMP stub"
```

I know I must be missing something that should be obvious... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach here is a bit confusing. when you created the new interface, the next step should have been to have the old bean implement the new interface, like so:

```
public class OldBean implements OldRemoteInterface, NewRemoteInterface {
```

Your old bean would get larger, yes, but this is the only way you can expand the functionality of your old bean without creating a new bean or touching the old interface.

The object being returned by getNewStuff() is just a plain object -- it is not remote. That's why you're getting serialization errors, because RMI is trying to transfer your NewRemoteInterface instance across the network. Annotating it with @Remote doesn't do anything (until you actually use the interface on a bean, deploy that bean and then retrieve it using DI or Contexts)

Comment: I see, I was expecting more "black magic" to be performed under the hood when the @Remote annotation was added.

Comment: I wish that was the case too! :)